# How to improve negative R square in DecisionTree Regressor

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I was trying to apply some regressor to make an IMDB rating predict. This is what I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data = pd.read_csv("D:/Code/imdb_project/movie_metadata.csv")
df = data[["duration","budget", "title_year","imdb_score"]]
df = df.dropna()
feature = np.array(df[["duration","budget","title_year"]])
rating = np.array(df["imdb_score"])

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(feature)
X = scaler.transform(feature)
y = rating
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size = 0.8, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 5)

regressor = DecisionTreeRegressor(criterion='mse')
regressor.fit(x_train, y_train)
regressor.score(x_test, y_test)
```

For clarification, my dataset contains 3 features: Budge, Release year, and duration, y is the IMDB rating. 
When applying this regressor for the test data, I always receive a negative R square (it works just fine with the train data.) I understand that R square can be negative but I am still wondering if there is a way that I can improve it? The only way I know is normalizing the data and I did it before fitting the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negative **R^2 score** means your model fits the data very poorly. In this case Decision tree may be too simple. Or maybe you've chosen wrong `criterion`.

I would recommend to try tune your model's hyperparameters or choose another one.

Comment: I think my model is overfitting because there is no limitation on max depth. So when I add the limitation, the score went positive. However, it is still low (0.23) and I am trying to make a comparison between model and the score is also low for kneighborsregressor too. Any suggestions for further improvement?

Comment: You could try `GridSearchCV` to find the best hyperparameters. And despite `DecisionTreeRegressor` and `KNeighborsRegressor` there're a lot of other regressors. Maybe the simpliest `LinearRegression` could help.